# So can I not use Android Studio on this computer? Missing SSSE3

Tags: ubuntu, troubleshooting, android-studio, emulator, android-x86

Tried to run a few emulators in Android Studio to test the basic activity and got this:

11:50 PM    Emulator: emulator: WARNING: Host CPU is missing the following feature(s) required for x86 emulation: SSSE3

11:50 PM    Emulator: Hardware-accelerated emulation may not work properly!

11:50 PM    Emulator: qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.ssse3 [bit 9]

11:50 PM    Emulator: qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.sse4.1 [bit 19]

11:50 PM    Emulator: qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.sse4.2 [bit 20]

I am running a AMD Athlon II X4 630 Processor which is a bit older on ubuntu 18.04 and I couldn't find a workaround. I am brand new to the app development world and would appreciate any advice getting over this hurdle. I don't have the money atm to buy a new system so ANY workaround would be helpful.

Comment: Do you not have a hardware device you can use?

Comment: I have 2 maybe? 1 ATT S4 and 1 Verizon S4. Is there no way to use the emulator to ensure compatibility on all devices? Format and stuff like that?

Comment: It's not showing support for the 630. Just the 860

Comment: It’s not asking for SSE3. It’s SSSE3, which is something different. SSE4a is also unrelated to SSE4.1 and SSE4.2. The emulator doesn’t lie. This CPU won’t cut it.

Comment: @DanielB D'oh - I missed the supplemental S. Deleting earlier comments.